# Get list of Javascript methods from C# WebBrowser or WatiN

Tags: javascript, watin

After a page loads, I'm trying to get a list of all JavaScript methods that exist on that page.

I know how to invoke Javascript from C# and C# from Javascript, the problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the original list of Javascript methods to execute.

I need the solution to be available in C# (via WatiN or WebBrowser Control)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using the .NET's Jint API. See here a video ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pqY_6-P-xU ) about a mini tool I created using this API for the [OWASP O2 Plaform](http://o2platform.com)